# Navigation guard keeps looping

Tags: vue.js

I have a guard for my routes which does work in all aspects apart from when I wish to check a permissions object related to that page prior to continuing onto the url.

I have separated out the logic for the permissions check into a function and console logging it out all elements are working, in that it finds the right object in the array, finds the right key and value, and allows or blocks accordingly.

My problem though is that when I go through this route hitting this function it loops endlessly and crashes the browser. I think my overarching logic is fine but have I screwed up its implementation somewhere?

```
function guard (to, from, next) {

var loggedin_state = store.state.user.auth.loggedin // Boolean
var user = store.state.user.user // Array
var token = store.state.user.auth.token // String
var entryUrl // String

if(entryUrl == null || entryUrl == undefined){
    entryUrl = to.path
}

if(loggedin_state == true) {
    // Is the user profile blank
    if(user == null) {
        this.$store.dispatch('user/get_user_information', null)
    }
    // If they tried a route before logging in that would have been stored
    if(entryUrl) {
        // Store the url before wiping it
        let url = entryUrl;
        // Wipe the entry url variable
        entryUrl = null;
        // Carry on to permission checking function
        return go_to_url(url);
    } else {
        // Go to stored url
        return next(to.path)
    }
} else {
    // Is there a token assigned? If so they are approved and just need the profile information
    if(token !== null) {
        loggedin_state = true
        this.$store.dispatch('user/get_user_information', null)
        return go_to_url(to.path);
    } else {
        // Store entry url before redirect for use after login
        entryUrl = to.path
        // Re-route to login page
        return next("/login");
    }
}

function go_to_url(url) {
    // Find matching object in user.permissions based upon url
    var view_permissions = [
        { "area": "all", "read": 1, "create": 0, "edit": 0, "delete": 0 },
        { "area": "dashboard", "read": 1, "create": 0, "edit": 0, "delete": 0 }
    ];
    // var view_permissions = store.state.user.permissions
    var view_permission = view_permissions.find(view => view.area === to.name);
    if(view_permission.read == 1) {
        // Go to url
        next(url);
    } else {
        // Re-route to somewhere
    }
};

};
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in passing a value to the next() function call. By removing that out it worked alright:

```
function guard (to, from, next) {

  console.log('To:')
  console.log(to)
  console.log('From:')
  console.log(from)
  console.log('EntryUrl: ' + entryUrl)

  // 1 - If no entry path was provided then set to 
  if(entryUrl == null || entryUrl == undefined){
    entryUrl = to.path
    console.log('EntryUrl: ' + entryUrl)
  }

  // 2 - Check if the user is marked as being logged in
  var loggedin_state = store.state.user.auth.loggedin
  if(loggedin_state == undefined) {
    store.commit('user/set_delete_session', null)
    return next("/login");
  }

  // 3 - If they are marked as logged in continue
  var user = store.state.user.user
  var token = store.state.user.auth.token
  if(loggedin_state == true) {

    // If the user isn't authorised with a token then send them to the log in page
    if(token == null) {
      store.commit('user/set_delete_session', null)
      return next("/login");
    }

    // If they've got a token but no user profile data acquire it
    if(user == null) {
      UserApi.get_user_information(response.data.token)
      .then(response => {
          store.commit('user/set_user', response.data)
      })
    }

    // If they tried a route before logging in that would have been stored
    if(entryUrl) {
      console.log('Go to saved URL')
      // Store the url before wiping it
      let url = entryUrl;
      // Wipe the entry url variable
      entryUrl = null;
      // Go to stored url
      return go_to_url(url);
    } else {
      console.log('Go to pointed url')
      // Carry on to permission checking function
      return go_to_url(to.path);
    }
  } else {

    // The user is not logged in. Store the URL they were trying to visit and redirect them to the login page
    entryUrl = to.path
    console.log('EntryUrl: ' + entryUrl)
    return next("/login");

  }

  function go_to_url(url) {
    console.log(url)

    // 1 - Grab the user permissions from the user profile
    var permissions_array = null
    if(user !== null) {
      permissions_array = user.permissions
    }
    console.log(permissions_array)

    // 2 - Check and route
    if(permissions_array !== null) {

      // Find the relevant permission object based upon the route name and the area key
      var view_permissions = permissions_array.find(view => view.area === to.name);
      console.log(view_permissions)

      // If a permission object was found check its status, if no object found assume it is okay to view
      if(view_permissions !== undefined) {
        // If set to 1 the user can view this route, else reroute to a permissions denied page 
        if(view_permissions.read == 1) {
          // Go to url
          console.log('GUARD - PROCEED')
          console.log(to.name)
          next();
        } else {
          console.log('GUARD - BLOCKED')
          return next("/permission-denied");
        }
      } else {
        return next()
      }

    }

  };

};
```